# Unable to import hurry.filesize module in Python?

Tags: python, module

I have using Python 2.6 with Django 1.4. I am able to import in python shell as:

```
from hurry.filesize import alternative
```

I am also able to import in Django shell as:

```
./manage.py shell

from hurry.filesize import alternative
```

But I get error while using it in the real Django project in the same machine. What's the problem?

Comment: What server do you use to host your Django? Maybe you have to adjust the PYTHONPATH (i.e., sys.path in Python) in the configuration of the server or the respective module.

Comment: Localhost. I have append the path of the module using sys.append() from python shell.

Comment: Sorry for being inprecise. What server *software*? The development-server? Apache?

Comment: The development server came with django. I am running Django locally.

Comment: this is not enough for us. what's the exact error? give us some more informations on your project configuration (folder hierarchy, where's that module etc etc)